# Facebook Messenger Customer Chat

Tags: javascript, facebook

Hello everyone i'm trying to find the doc to use fb-customerchat which is used, for example, on this website https://bodeaz.com/collections/leggings. If anyone could give me indication on how to use it it would be very nice.
Thank you

Comment: Not sure what functionality on that site you are referring to (don’t see any “fb-customerchat”), but I suppose it can only mean https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform

Comment: Can't you see the facebook messenger icon on the bottom right corner ?

Comment: Yeah, can see it now, didn’t show up on my other computer. Yes, that is Messenger platform functionality. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/send-to-messenger-plugin

Comment: Hello Leo, Are you able to crack above functionality? I want to achieve the same

Answer (score 0):

It uses [Customer Chat plugin (beta)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin). This is a fairly new feature that let's you integrate your chatbots into your pages.